# Jquery Ajax Displaying error message on login form when login fails

Tags: jquery, ajax

Below is the part where the login is validated.

```
$.ajax({
  url : '/api/auth/login',
  headers: { 
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  crossDomain: true,
  method: 'POST',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType:'json',
  data: JSON.stringify(login),
  success : function(data) {
    alert('Logged in successfully....');
    $(location).attr('href', "/ui/index.html");
  },
});
```

I have the following placeholder in login box

```
<p id="err-msg"> </p>
<p id="success-msg"> </p>
```

I have 2 paragraphs with id `success-msg` and `err-msg`. Instead of the alert('Logged in successfully....'); it should be something else and the error or success message should reflect on the form.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean when the ajax request fails? Or the `data` parameter in the `success` will contain an error? Try `console.log(data)` instead of the `alert(Logged in...`

Comment: Can you clarify what the question is here?

Comment: What is the error? Will adding `error` function like: `error : function(data) { ... }` solve your prob?

Comment: What response you get in "data" of ajax success?  If response data itself contains error you can use it to validate and display the error. If you want ajax fail error then you can use  error : function(data) { ... }

Comment: When ajax request fails..

Comment: @sunil on success it will be routed to dashboard. So no problem. Only when it errors, i have a paragraph with id "err-msg" in the login form. That should be filled with a message

Comment: That's as easy as `$("#err-msg").html("Your success message here!");` Maybe you want to work through a basic JavaScript tutorial though.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $.ajax({
                url : '/api/auth/login',
                headers: { 
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                crossDomain: true,
                method: 'POST',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType:'json',
                data: JSON.stringify(login),
                success : function(data) { // executes in ajax success
                    if(data.success){ //assuming data contains success and message
                      alert('Logged in successfully....');
                      $(location).attr('href', "/ui/index.html");
                    }
                    else{
                      alert(data.error.msg) // assuming data contains error                       and message
                    }
                },
                error : function(data) { // executes only if ajax fails
                    alert('Error....');
                }
            });
```

Ajax error executes only when ajax call fails like no resource found, no connectivity etc. If your API sending response in success or error, then it's captured in ajax success only. From there you need to identify error or success from incoming response. Note that if API sending error response then it's not ajax failure.

Comment: I am getting below error in console when the username or password is invalid. VM391:4 POST http://localhost:8082/api/auth/login 500 (Response code 401 mapped as failure.)   But the alert doesnt appear on error

Comment: Was a problem with the API I was calling. Thanks it works!!